# Failing shell script

Tags: shell

Shell script should check the file is arrived within in 30 min. If it hasn't arrived within 30 min the script should fail.

```
interval=2
((end_time=${SECONDS}+30))

directory=/app/mus/storepick/dataflowextract/shell
file=backup.cfg

while ((${SECONDS} < ${end_time}))
do
    if [[ -r ${directory}/${file} ]]
    then
        echo "File has arrived."
        exit 0
    fi
    sleep ${interval}
done

echo "File not arrivied !!!"

exit 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what isn't working correctly. However, I'm going to guess that the script exits too early, claiming the file hasn't arrived.

You're calculating end_time as `${SECONDS} + 30` - which is only 30 *seconds* into the future, not 30 *minutes*. For 30 minutes into the future, you would need `${SECONDS} + 1800`.

Comment: Thanks!!!  my code is working properly , but when it will not recivied a file within 30 min the script should get fail , 30 sec i had kept for my testing purpose.